# Is there good way to replace all couchDB objects in a set?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, pouchdb, nosql

One of my node servers has a job of checking an FTP for an XML file, if one is found it takes that, converts it to JSON. Now its job is to wipe a couchdb database, and have all of the new data found in the XML file replace what was there previously.

Now since I don't want the database to actually be empty (or non-existent) at any point I haven't simply destroyed then recreated it with the new data set. My node server has been replicating from the database to local pouchdb, wiping it (soft deletion), then putting all of the new data in it, then replicating up to the couchdb database.

Seems like the downloading should be completely unnecessary and there should be a way to do this with hard deletion. Is there any way to simply replace all objects in a current CouchDB database with a new set of objects which my node server would replicate up to it?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Would a purge + compact run regularly fix the soft deletion vs hard deletion issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB keeps the document revision history in a tree, so replacing a document (let's say a document with an _id of 'x') with a newer version requires you to know the existing revision's _id/_rev pair in or to be able to update it.

So if you need to update document 'x' you would have to

```
 // fetch the document first
 curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/mydb/x
 { "_id": "x", "_rev": "45-123", "name": "fred"}
 // to be able to update it
 curl -X PUT -d'{ "_id": "x", "_rev": "45-123", "name": "Fred Smith"}' http://localhost:5984/mydb/x
 { "ok": "true", "_id": "x", "_rev": "46-456"}
```

You could rewrite your job to do this GET/PUT operation for each document that has changed.

If you need the data to be wiped prior to importing the new data, then simply create a new database, e.g. "mydb2017-09-22", import the data into it and tell the app that is using the data to use "mydb2017-09-22" as the source of truth. You can then safely safely delete the previous canonical database. This avoids the replication step in your current solution.

Purge is not supported in current CouchDB as it messes up implementations where the data is replicated around. Compaction is for removing the bodies of older, unwanted revisions of documents to save space.

Not knowing everything about your problem, I would suggest looking at the "one database per import" solution as it allows you to simply switch between data sets when the import is complete and it cleans up after itself by deleting the old database.

Comment: "If you need the data to be wiped prior to importing the new data, then simply create a new database, e.g. "mydb2017-09-22", import the data into it and tell the app that is using the data to use "mydb2017-09-22" as the source of truth" . . . . . How would I be able to tell the app to use that database instead, surely it's better to have databases with static names which the app syncs from

Comment: It depends what is more important to you. It sounds like you are going to a lot of trouble replicating data about the place. My suggestion creates a clean database for each import and then your app switches to the new database when it's ready. It plays to the strengths of CouchDB which deletes entire databases nicely, but leaves data hanging around when deleting or updating documents. 

The short answer to your question is that there isn't a way to replace all the documents in a set without deleting the database and recreating it, but that would leave some time without data.

Comment: Ok thanks Glynn, I'll have a static named database with a single object telling my app which databases to use for what so that I can apply your solution. I'll be back on that next week